# Max/Min to logical operator transformation and viceversa

Tags: logic

I have some doubts in transforming conditions that involve max/min in logical operator condition and viceversa. In particular, should be (I put some examples, I would know if I'm right and the reasoning to derive the transformations):

$7 \leqslant \min(4+2x, 6+x)$ is equivalent to $4+2x \geqslant 7$ AND $6+x \geqslant 7$

$7 \leqslant \max(4+2x, 6+x)$ is equivalent to $4+2x \geqslant 7$ OR $6+x \geqslant 7$

AND (on $i$ from $0$ to $n$) OR ($k=1\dotsm m$) $a+ib \leqslant k$ is equivalent to $\max_i (a+ib) \leqslant m*(a \text{ particular } k)$

Thank you

Comment: What set of numbers are those inequalities supposed to apply to?

Answer (score 1):

Let us say $X\leq \min(A, B)$. If so, then $X\leq A$ and $X\leq B$.

If a number is at most as great as the least of two other numbers, then it must be at most as great as one of them (their minimum) and it must be at most as great as the other (which is at least as great as their minimum).

OTOH: Let us say $X\leq \max(A, B)$. If so, then $X\leq A$ or $X\leq B$.

If a number is at least as great as the greatest of two other numbers, then all we can say is that it must be least as great as one of them (their maximum).   It *may* be greater than the other.

We can argue similarly for the case of greater inequality.

Thus we have the following equivalences.

$$\begin{align*}
X\leq \min(A, B) \iff & (X\leq A) \wedge (X\leq B)
\\
X\leq \max(A, B) \iff & (X\leq A) \vee (X\leq B)
\\
X\geq \min(A, B) \iff & (X\geq A) \vee (X\geq B)
\\
X\geq \max(A, B) \iff & (X\geq A) \wedge (X\geq B)
\end{align*}$$